# Menu underneath Android Actionbar component

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to make a UI like this http://d.pr/i/ZQxO but I don't think so that android ActionBar component has the provision to add menu layout like this. What can be the possible workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: Your image url not working. Better delete or edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple option menus. Have look on [official samples](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) or even better do it breadcrumb

Comment: this is for the options menu and not for nested menus. I know about this but it doesn't seem to work for nested menus.

Comment: Sorry, you will need to explain more in details what you trying to achieve as that image is not exactly self explenatory

Comment: when I click on a tap horizontal menu options should be shown regarding that tab.